# RecyclerView inside persistent bottom sheet onItemClick not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

This is my bottomSheet layout

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="name"
        type="String" />
</data>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#C6C6C6"

    app:behavior_peekHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_music_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="@{name}"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_play_list_songs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_sheet_music_name"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_no_music"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bottom_sheet_music_name"
        android:background="#B5B5B5"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_music_off_24"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

everything can be clicked in bottomsheet but when I click an Item in recyclerview , adapter's interface method not called.
while when I use recyclerview and Adapter in a Fragment or a Activity , can click on Items and get result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked the right binding with the right type of your Item ?
Such as

```
if(mFormElementsList.get(position).getType().equals("text")){
        return VIEW_TYPE_SINGLE ;
    }
    if(mFormElementsList.get(position).getType().equals("radio-select") || mFormElementsList.get(position).getType().equals("radio")){
        return VIEW_TYPE_RADIO ;
```

if so, please check your binding of the adapter is related to the good RV :

```
        mBinding.bottomsheetmap.rvFiltersMap.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: thanks to your respond. accidentally wrote twice implementation of the same adapter , and i changed one and its working.